# Wifi issues old Zotac Motherboard

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, lubuntu

I have recently freshly installed Lubuntu 20.10 onto an old PC I had lying around. It has a Zotac-h67-C-E motherboard and I'm having some issues with the onboard wifi (rt2800pci chipset).

At startup everything seems fine however after a day or two the wifi silently drops, and I can no longer see any wifi networks to connect to. I've tried restarting networking however it seems only a full system reboot will resolve the issue.

I've tried a USB wifi card (Atheros) however upon plugging that in the system locks up and I'm forced to hard reboot (I've tried both with and without the rt2800pci modules blacklisted).

Can anyone help me figure this out? I've previously worked around the issue with a wifi to ethernet bridge but that was quite brittle so I'm looking to solve this more reliably, either by fixing the onboard wifi, or using a USB wifi that is reasonably easy to install and manage. Note that although the motherboard has a PCI express slot, it's not possible to use it due to the size of the CPU fan I have - so sadly that's not an option

Comment: Yes this is a desktop case,  however the wifi antenna are on the outside of the case. I am able to connect to the wifi fine, with strong signal,  when it works. However after a couple of days the wifi is completely unavailable (network manager doesn't even acknowledge there being a wifi card)

Comment: No, because the issue is with the wireless card/driver

Comment: I can connect fine to the internet via ethernet cable. I have used an external antenna placed far away from the case and the issue persists. It's a brand new install of ubuntu 20.10 so we can probably rule out networking software issues -otherwise lots of people would be having the same issue. Ockhams razor suggests its wifi card/drivers I'd have thought?

Comment: Issue resolved using a different usb wifi adapter